# Properly Set Up Loop/ If Statements

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm currently creating a program that will take user input.

If the user input contains `_`, then a variable substring will then equal the first 4 characters (0,4) of that input.
From there, a loop is run that loops through an array, and within that loop is an `If` statement that determines if the array contains the substring. And if so, the position of the array element that contains the substring is then equal to the same position of a different element array. And if any element from that array doesn't contain the substring, a MsgBox displays saying error.

Currently, if the user inputs text that in fact is a substring of that input is contained within the array, it is still prompting the error message, as well as displaying the correct outcome. How would I correctly set this up to where if the substring is not found within the array, the MsgBox will prompt the error, and if it is, only the correct outcome will be executed. Here's what I currently have:
And yes I know that both arrays don't contain the same amount of elements, I'm just testing the first three values.

```vb
Dim i As Integer
Dim subString As String
Dim IdValues = New String() {"ADC_123", "AAA_123", "AAB_123", "EFGH_Company", "ABB_456", "ABC_456"}
Dim ValueValues = New String() {"Happy", "Sad", "Mad", "Excited", "Joyful"}
Dim charText As Char
charText = "_"

If txtDataEntry.Text.Contains(charText) Then ' if statement to determine if text contains a "_"
    subString = txtDataEntry.Text.Substring(0, 4) 'sets variable subString to a substring of text data
    For i = 0 To IdValues.Length - 1 'looping through array
        If IdValues(i).Contains(subString) And txtDataEntry.Text.Contains(IdValues(i)) Then
            MsgBox("Success, the position is at position " & i)
            IdValues(i) = ValueValues(i) 'new array position now equals the IdValue array where the substring is found
            lblValueResult.Text = IdValues(i) 'prints outcome to label
        Else
            MsgBox("Error")
        End If
    Next i
Else
    MsgBox("Sorry, no value was found.")
End If
```

So if the user enters `AAA_123` it will create a substring `AAA_` and determine if the `IdValues` array contains that substring. It is prompting the correct execution, but it is also prompting the Error message. How should I correctly set this up.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Remove the inner `Else` branch, Have a boolean flag, `found`. Set it to `true` when you find a match, and add `exit for`. After the loop, if `found` is still `false`, display "Error".

Answer (score 0):

Using a Boolean for these types of iteration process is always better than playing around with if else .Please try the below answer

```
 Dim isValueFound As Boolean = False

        Dim i As Integer
        Dim subString As String
        Dim IdValues = New String() {"ADC_123", "AAA_123", "AAB_123", "EFGH_Company", "ABB_456", "ABC_456"}
        Dim ValueValues = New String() {"Happy", "Sad", "Mad", "Excited", "Joyful"}
        Dim charText As Char
        charText = "_"

        If txtDataEntry.Text.Contains(charText) Then ' if statement to determine if text contains a "_"
            subString = txtDataEntry.Text.Substring(0, 4) 'sets variable subString to a substring of text data
            For i = 0 To IdValues.Length - 1 'looping through array
                If IdValues(i).Contains(subString) And txtDataEntry.Text.Contains(IdValues(i)) Then
                    MsgBox("Success, the position is at position " & i)
                    IdValues(i) = ValueValues(i) 'new array position now equals the IdValue array where the substring is found
                    lblValueResult.Text = IdValues(i) 'prints outcome to label
                    isValueFound = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i


            If isValueFound = False Then
                MsgBox("Error : Not Found")
            End If

        Else
            MsgBox("Sorry, no value was found.")
        End If
```